# Server incorrectly interpreting JavaScript encoded query params

Tags: javascript, urlencode, query-string

I'm finding that the Phoenix API I'm working on is not handling encoded url query parameters as I would expect - the maps are not correctly formed and are evaluating to `nil`... it seems that Phoenix is not recognizing `%3D` as a param's equal sign. Best if I just illustrate the problem:

On the client side, I'd like to make a `GET` request to the following url:

```
localhost:4000/api/v1/users?test=testing
```

I'm checking for query params and encoding them with the following function:

```
const encode = (url) => {
    return (/[?]/.test(url) ? url.slice(0, url.indexOf("?") + 1) + encodeURIComponent(url.split("?")[1]) : url)
}
```

and so the request goes out to

```
localhost:4000/api/v1/users?test%3Dtesting
```

However, when I `IO.inspect params` on the server, it logs

```
%{"test=testing" => nil}
```

If I don't encode the query params, then the server handles the params as one would expect - `%{"test" => "testing"}`.

It seems that I'm not correctly encoding the params on the client. Can anyone clarify my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is correct -- escaping the `=` as `%3D` means that the `=` becomes part of the key. Here's a simple Node.js snippet using the popular `qs` package which shows the same behavior:

```
> var qs = require('qs');
> qs.parse('test%3Dtesting');
{ 'test=testing': '' }
> qs.parse('test=testing');
{ test: 'testing' }
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with the code, but you probably want to use `encodeURI` instead of `encodeURIComponent` which doesn't escape `=`:

```
> encodeURIComponent('f o o=bar')
'f%20o%20o%3Dbar'
> encodeURI('f o o=bar')
'f%20o%20o=bar'
```